# Is roundDown(roundDown(x/n)/n) = roundDown(x/n²)?

Tags: floating-point, rounding-error

It somehow feels wrong, but I can't find an example for it being wrong.

n and x are positive integers.

Comment: This needs a bit of clarification, perhaps. Is $n$ an integer? Positive? What exactly does the function "float" do?

Comment: @HansLundmark better now?

Comment: Yes, that's clearer!

Comment: @HansLundmark Do you may have an answer?

Answer (score 3):

If you write $x$ in base $n$ you have $x=x_k \dots x_2 x_1 x_0$
where each digit $x_i$ belongs to $\{ 0,1,\dots,n-1 \}$.

Take $a=x_k\dots x_2$, $b=x_1$ and $c=x_0$; this means that
$$x=an^2+bn+c$$
with $0 \le a$, $0 \le b < n$ and $0 \le c < n$.

Now we can compute
$$\frac{x}{n} = an + b + \frac{c}{n}$$
which rounds down to $an+b$.

Do you think you can continue the reasoning from there, and find the left-hand side and right-hand side of your formula in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$?

Comment: If I did everything right that means the given equaty is actually right. Did I do something wrong? How should I post my answer to your thread? (I'm new here.)

Comment: As long as you've convinced yourself that you get $a=a$, I'm happy. :-) If you like, you can post your solution as a separate answer for practice (and then people can give feedback), but that's not necessary.